# How can I detect whether an Android APK has debuggable set to true or false in its manifest without installing it?

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

As the title says, I'd like to be able to find whether an APK has debuggable set to true or false on a computer without having to install it on the device, run it and see whether it shows up in DDMS or not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one of those "easy once you know how" things - Use the aapt tool to inspect the manifest.

```
aapt dump xmltree YourApp.apk AndroidManifest.xml | grep debuggable
```

That command will give you a dump of the compiled form of the AndroidManifest.xml file-  the output will look something like

> A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0x0

(Actual output from my command prompt) in that example, the 0x0 indicates false.

Comment: Thanks, I just found an alternate method with `l -a` too.

Comment: If you want to know the state of the debuggable flag in the manifest you can do as @Alexander suggests. However, if you want to know if an apk is actually debuggable, you also need to see if the `grep` is empty. If your manifest has no debuggable flag, it will default to false. From the docs: `You can disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute from the <application> tag in your manifest file, or by setting the android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file.` You can always just look at the whole manifest by removing `| grep debuggable` from the above code.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently `aapt` can do it:

```
aapt l -a app.apk | grep debuggable
```

will return either:

```
A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff (means debuggable is true)
```

or

```
A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0x0 (means debuggable is false)
```

Answer (score 5):

For window user can use following command:

```
aapt l -a <apk with path> | findstr debuggable
```

will return either:

```
A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
-> this means debuggable is true.
```

or

```
A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0x0
-> this means debuggable is false.
```

Comment: For me at least this returned nothing!

Comment: If it returns nothing, that means the `debuggable` flag is not explicitly set, so the debuggable flag defaults to false, according to the android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element