# Unity Android can't publish APK, signed as debug

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk, publish

I am trying to upload an APK built in Unity3D to the Play Store, but it says I can't upload it because it's signed as debug mode. However, it's not! I've done absolutely everything in every forum:

- Development checkbox unchecked.
- Keystore set
- Microsoft Visual Studio switched from Debug to Release
- In the android manifest I had "debuggable=true", I removed it.

What else must I do? I think that's all.

Comment: *"In the android manifest I had "debuggable=true", I removed it."* Which irectly i you find the manifest?

Comment: Where did I find the manifest? (I don't understand your question). I'm using the Android plugin for Unity, which allows you to have a Manifest, a Resources folder and more Native features, like in Android Studio.

Comment: You don't need a plugin to change the manifest. You should that plugin since it could be changing the manifest. See [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/upload-failed-you-uploaded-an-apk-that-was-signed-in-debug-mode.188537/) post for how to properly build and sign Android apk from Unity

Comment: Sorry but I inherited this project from another programmer, it's already set up and finished, in fact the app is already published and now I need to make an update. Furthermore, the Android plugin is supported by Unity itself, so it should work fine. And I already read all the Unity posts and guides about how to publish an apk.

Comment: @Sertilou did you find a solution?

Comment: @DataGreed srry I asked this long ago, I don't even remember what project for. I think I didn't solve it in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Hello friends if you already publish your app and you want to do an update follow this.

1. If you are sure about your keystorage settings and if development
   build is not active continue with second part.
2. If you are using Facebook SDK or some Google services there's a
   configuration problem. Go to Assets > Plugins > Android >
   AndroidManifest.xml and find android:debuggable= and just set it
   false like:

   android:debuggable="false"

That's all guys. Thank you and bye bye!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so in order to sign the app for distribution via Play Store you also have to add a key and sign your apk with it. To do this:

1. Find the Publishing Settings under Player Settings
2. Create a new keystore by selecting a keystore name and password (confirm the password), select "browse" to save the keystore
3. Select "Create a new key" under Key Alias
4. A new window opens; enter the necessary information.
5. Select the newly created key.
6. Build

Your app is now signed, you can upload it to Play Store

Answer (score 0):

All the Play store does is look at your APK using public tools. You can reproduce exactly what it does.

To check the signing key (which will need to match to update the app):

```
`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk`
```

To look at the manifest you use a tool called `aapt` which comes with the android SDK. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160971/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-android-apk-has-debuggable-set-to-true-or-false-in-i) tells you how to use it to tell if your APK is debuggable.

If your APK is debuggable as defined by the method above then you haven't changed everything you need.